# Pass Custom Variables In GraphQL Query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, graphql, apollo

I have an `UpdateUserPage` which can call mutations in different ways depending on how many input variables are being passed for eg:

only firstname is updated

```
    mutation{
            updateUser(email: "d@d.com",
            input: {firstName:"check"}){id}
            }
```

both, firstname & lastName are updated:

```
    mutation{
            updateUser(email: "d@d.com",
            input: {firstName:"check", lastName: "new"}){id}
            }
```

Query in my code right now:

```
export const UPDATE_USER = gql`
  mutation UpdateUser($email: String!, $firstName: String, $lastName: String) {
    updateUser(
      email: $email
      input: { firstName: $firstName, lastName: $lastName }
    ) {
      id
      firstName
    }
  }
`;
```

What I want:

I want to change my form in such a way that if the user enters only the firstName and leaves the lastName field blank,
then only firstName should be updated, meaning that the first type of query should be used and the lastName should remain what it was before the mutation was called.

What's Happening Now:

For instance, previously the firstName was HELLO and lastName was WORLD. Now, I am updating the firstName to CHECK and leaving the lastName option blank. So when it returns values, it should return CHECK as the firstName and un-modified WORLD as the lastName. However, right now, it shows lastName as undefined.
If I inspect the Resources, I see this:

```
{"operationName":"UpdateUser","variables":{"email":"c@c.com","firstName":"Final"},"query":"mutation UpdateUser($email: String!, $firstName: String, $lastName: String) {\n updateUser(email: $email, input: {firstName: $firstName, lastName: $lastName}) {\n id\n firstName\n __typename\n }\n}\n"} Looks like the lastName is still being passed in the mutation.
```

which means that the lastName is still being used in the mutation. So, I need a way to pass custom variables into my query:

`$input : Object!`doesn't work.

Here's the code for my whole page:

```
export default function UpdateUserPage() {
  const [isSubmitted, setIsSubmitted] = useState(false);
  const [isUpdated, setIsUpdated] = useState(false);

  const [updateUser] = useMutation(UPDATE_USER);
  let submitForm = (
    email: string,
    firstName: string,
    lastName: string,
  ) => {
    setIsSubmitted(true);

    if (email && (firstName || lastName || phoneNumber)) {
      const vars:any = {
        email
      };
    if( firstName !== ''){
      vars.firstName = firstName}
      if( lastName !== ''){
        vars.lastName = lastName}

      updateUser({
        variables: vars})
        .then(({ data }: any) => {
          setIsUpdated(true);
          console.log(updateUser);
          console.log('FN: ', data.updateUser.firstName);
          console.log('LN: ', data.updateUser.lastName);
        })
        .catch((error: { message: string }) => {
          setIsUpdated(false);
        });
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Formik
        initialValues={{
          firstName: '',
          lastName: '',
          email: '',
          phoneNumber: '',
        }}
        onSubmit={(values, actions) => {
          setTimeout(() => {
            alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
            actions.setSubmitting(false);
          }, 1000);
        }}
        validationSchema={schema}>
        {props => {
          const {
            values: { firstName, lastName, email, phoneNumber },
            errors,
            touched,
            handleChange,
            isValid,
            setFieldTouched,
          } = props;
          const change = (name: string, e: FormEvent) => {
            e.persist();
            handleChange(e);
            setFieldTouched(name, true, false);
          };
          return (
            <div className="main-content">
              <form
                style={{ width: '100%' }}
                onSubmit={e => {
                  e.preventDefault();
                  submitForm(email, firstName, lastName);
                }}>
                <div>
                  <TextField
                    variant="outlined"
                    margin="normal"
                    id="email"
                    name="email"
                    helperText={touched.email ? errors.email : ''}
                    error={touched.email && Boolean(errors.email)}
                    label="Email"
                    value={email}
                    onChange={change.bind(null, 'email')}
                  />
                  <br></br>
                  <TextField
                    variant="outlined"
                    margin="normal"
                    id="firstName"
                    name="firstName"
                    helperText={touched.firstName ? errors.firstName : ''}
                    error={touched.firstName && Boolean(errors.firstName)}
                    label="First Name"
                    value={firstName}
                    onChange={change.bind(null, 'firstName')}
                  />
                  <br></br>
                  <TextField
                    variant="outlined"
                    margin="normal"
                    id="lastName"
                    name="lastName"
                    helperText={touched.lastName ? errors.lastName : ''}
                    error={touched.lastName && Boolean(errors.lastName)}
                    label="Last Name"
                    value={lastName}
                    onChange={change.bind(null, 'lastName')}
                  />
                  <CustomButton
                    text={'Update User Info'}
                  />
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          );
        }}
      </Formik>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Edit:

From the schema:

```
input: UpdateUserInput!
```

```
input UpdateUserInput {
  email: String
  firstName: String
  lastName: String
  phoneNumber: String
}
```

Now, I have done this:

```
interface UpdateUserInput {
  email: String
  firstName: String
  lastName: String
  phoneNumber: String
}

export const UPDATE_USER = gql`
  mutation UpdateUser($email: String!, $input : UpdateUserInput) {
    updateUser(
      email: $email
      input: $input
    ) {
      id
      firstName
    }
  }
`;
```

However, when I submit the form, I still get this error:

```
GraphQL error: The variable `input` type is not compatible with the type of the argument `input`.
Expected type: `UpdateUserInput`.
```

Probably because I'm still passing `vars` from my main `UpdateUserPage`. How would I change that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of your `$input` variable would be whatever is the type of the `input` argument on `updateUser`. If you didn't write the GraphQL schema yourself, you would need to check your API's documentation or GraphiQL/GraphQL Playground interface to determine the type to use.

Using a single variable (`$input`) instead of multiple ones for each field (`$firstName` and `$lastName`) is the preferred way of doing things. That said, there is nothing wrong with your query as is. You current query:

```
mutation ($email: String!, $firstName: String, $lastName: String) {
  updateUser(
    email: $email
    input: { firstName: $firstName, lastName: $lastName }
  ){
    id
  }
}
```

with the variables `{"email": "c@c.com", "firstName": "Final"}` would be ***equivalent*** to

```
mutation ($email: String!, $input: WhateverYourInputTypeIs) {
  updateUser(
    email: $email
    input: $input
  ){
    id
  }
}
```

with `{"email": "c@c.com", "input": { "firstName": "Final"} }`.

In both cases, the arguments passed to the resolver on the server side will be the same. If you are ending up with the wrong value for `lastName` after the mutation runs, then this is an issue with how the resolver is handling the arguments it receives.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! I understood the type now. However, I am having a problem defining it in my code correctly? Could you see the edit in my question? Probably some minor mistake.

Comment: The argument is non-nullable, so you need to make sure your variable is as well (i.e. append a `!` to the type).

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to modify your interface so that the fields are not required.

```
interface UpdateUserInput {
  email?: String
  firstName?: String
  lastName?: String
  phoneNumber?: String
}
```

By adding a question mark to the fields you are making them optional so that you can pass one or more at a time.